# Android ORMLite without context

Tags: android, ormlite

Is there any way to access the ORMLite DatabaseHelper ***without*** application context? 
I have a polyhierarchy in my data structure, but I always only save the parents in the database, and would like to retrieve the children with SQL statements.

I would prefer doing this without having to use Context, especially for unit testing. Is this possible, or do I always need to have context to interact with the database?

Answer (score 1):

When you follow the examples, you initiate a database helper or manager once, with a base context from your starting Activity or its parent.

From that point on you don't need to re-create this again with any context.

You will need to provide a context at one point however to initiate it the first time.

Comment: The problem is, that I do not have access to the Activity in the Data class. The only thing I can currently think of is passing the DatabaseHelper to the method, but I would like to avoid having to mix data level code with application level code. Maybe that makes clear what I want to do.

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is. Your application is forced to start off in some Activity. Give this activity parent, or use an Application app to once call DatabaseManager.init(this); From that point on you can use the DatabaseManager.getInstance or whatever you make of it, to acces this without needing a Context again.

Comment: I have a class `Category`, which can have any amount of Subcategories and parentcategories. In the Database, I only store the Parent Categories. The interface for Category defines a method `getSubCategories`, which is supposed to collect the subcategories with an SQL query. I would very much prefer to be able to create a database interaction without having to access the activity (i.e. calling it from the activity, passing the DatabaseHelper to the method).